# How to connect to Windows Share Without Password without modifying Windows?

Tags: networking, mount, shared-folders

I'm trying to access the sdcard that is inserted in my HP Officejet Pro 8500A.

My research shows that it should be accessible via

The IP and the folder `memory_card`.  For instance if the printer's ip is: `192.168.1.33`:

For Windows:

```
\\192.168.1.33\memory_card
```

For Unix:

```
smb://192.168.1.33/memory_card
```

On my Windows machine you can browse or share the folder from the file browser without a username or password prompt.  However, on Ubuntu I'm getting a username and password prompt when I try to browse or connect to the resource using Nautilus or any of the other file browsers such as Nemo.

I also tried to mount it with `gvfs-mount` as what I do with many other shares that has passwords.  It still prompts for a username and password, whereas there isn't in this case.

More research shows solutions such as providing "guest/hp" for the "username/password" (https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~klada/?site=projects&id=hpmem).

I tried this command:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.15.90/memory_card /mnt/ -o username=guest,password=hp
```

It has the following permission error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I've been trying to search for a cifs option that recognizes there isn't a user name or password to for the share.

From HP Support:
http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Inkjet-Printing/Accessing-SD-Card-over-network-Officejet-Pro-8600/td-p/1259641

Comment: The usename and password prompt is optional. There should be and option of connecting as anonymous user, if the share is configured to accept passwordless connections.

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks.  I forgot to include the detail that there is an anonymous option nautilus.  However, it will not connect to the share.  It responses the same way my normal shares respond if I try to connect to one of my regular shares that has passwords, but try to use anonymous to connect.

Comment: @Videonauth The user, as in this case, **don't have access to modify Windows**.  Look at details of the previous comment.

Comment: Retracted my CV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option `sec=ntlm` needs to be specified.  The `sec` specifies the security modem.  ntlm used to be the default mode and didn't need specification.

You can mount the (the HP printer sdcard) device with:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.15.90/memory_card /mnt/ -o sec=ntlm
```

This will provide **ntlm** for password hashing, whereas you won't be prompt for a password to access the mount.